# struts2 access session var in sj:head

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have a problem with session var in sj:head:

```
<sj:head locale="%{#session.language}" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="%{#session.viewTheme}" />
```

Doesn't set either locale or theme. Variables are set properly, line below displays correct values:

```
selected locale: <s:property value="%{#session.language}"/><br>
selected theme: <s:property value="%{#session.viewTheme}"/>
```

I played with #session.var %{#session.var}  and similar and none of them works. How can I use session vars in sj:head?

Comment: what is your language, what is your theme, are you sure, these are all exists?

Comment: Yes, when I set them 'manually' i mean locale="en" and jquerytheme="sunny" everything works.

Comment: Hmm it seems it was something wrong with server/deployment. After restart of the system everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

for your theme problem, try this:

**Theme** try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#jquery_theme_link').attr('href',
                               'struts/themes/'
                               +<s:property value="%{#session.viewTheme}"/>
                               +'/jquery-ui.css');
});
```

**Locale** try this:

```
<sj:head locale="%{#session.locale}"/>
```

which will inject strut locale. if you wanna change locale, you can change it using struts, make sure

```
<interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
```

in your stack.

Comment: It seems problem was with server/deployment. After restart of the system everything works as it should. But thanks for this other solution.